# typescript const x = [...this.x]

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax

I have some inherited typescript code that looks like this (inside of a function):

```
const Statuses = [...this.Statuses]
```

this.Statuses refers to an array  of status codes (defined as Statuses = status[];) defined inside the same .ts file. Subsequent to the line above, the code operates on Statuses

I'm trying to understand what the [...this.var] syntax does? Why not simply refer to this.Statuses in the first place?

Yes, I'm new to javascript/typescript....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript ES6 or JS 2016, added lots of new features. This is one of them. Please take 30min of urs to read ES6. It will help you to understand new syntax. 
https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/

Comment: @DeepakSharma: There is no such thing as JS 2016. I think you mean ES2015.

Comment: Whatever man, i gave example with attached link. nothing personal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "[spread notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)", it spreads out `this.Statuses` (which must be some kind of Iterable, such as an array) into discrete elements. In this case, those form a new array (because the `...this.Statuses` is within `[]`, which creates an array).

So if `this.Statuses` is an array, it's functionally identical to `const Statuses = this.Statuses.slice();` (or also the following).

If `this.Statuses` is another kind of Iterable, it's functionally identical to `const Statuses = Array.from(this.Statuses);`.

Comment: @jcalz: OMG, talk about auto-pilot. Fixed, thanks. (I literally said "...it spreads out..." and yet still missed I'd said "rest". Sigh. At least I didn't call it an operator. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

It's a aesthetically-pleasing way of *copying* an array, to avoid mutations to the original. It uses the spread syntax, as mentioned in other answers.

```js
const a = [ 1 ]
const b = a
const c = [...a]

b.push(2)
c.push(3)

console.log(` original: ${a}`)
console.log(`reference: ${b}`)
console.log(`     copy: ${c}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). It allows to copy items from one array (or object) to another. In your case it's used to make a shallow copy of `this.Statuses` to avoid original array mutations. Thanks for this when you for example push new item to `Statuses` the original array (`this.Statuses`) will remain unchanged.